# vk api сбрасывает scope

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

```
$data = [
 'client_id' => $vKappId,
 'redirect_uri' => 'myUrl',
 'scope' => '501202911',
 'display' => 'page',
 'response_type' => 'code'
];
                            
$url = 'https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?' . http_build_query($data);
```

далее после перехода сразу же видно что vk овершенно не хочет видеть мой scope[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

так же это видно в url

[https://id.vk.com/auth?return_auth_hash=5de67ae900d8d28386&redirect_uri={myUrl}&redirect_uri_hash=bbf3d7889a0dabbe6d&force_hash=&app_id=51851697&response_type=code&code_challenge=&code_challenge_method=&scope=65536&state=](https://id.vk.com/auth?return_auth_hash=5de67ae900d8d28386&redirect_uri=%7BmyUrl%7D&redirect_uri_hash=bbf3d7889a0dabbe6d&force_hash=&app_id=51851697&response_type=code&code_challenge=&code_challenge_method=&scope=65536&state=)

Comment: расшифруйте что у вас там в scope то и ссылку на доку. А то вдруг вы там телефон запрашиваете, а он только в vk id доступен.

Comment: Чтобы точно не ошибиться со scope взял отсюда его https://vkhost.github.io/
Вцелом мне самое важное получить доступ к сообщениям и диалогам. Но как бы я не менял scope
0 реакции vk сам подменяет его на тот что я написал или вовсе на 0

Comment: У ребят получается такая ссылка
https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=6121396&scope=501202911&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&display=page&response_type=token&revoke=1

Comment: что мешало запросить `scope=messages` как велено в [документации ВК](https://dev.vk.com/ru/reference/access-rights) ?

Comment: я вот даже не знаю чего там наскладывать можно, чтобы получить 9значеное значение начинающееся с 5.

Comment: `0001 1101 1101 1111 1011 1111 1101 1111` вот у вас биты выставлены. 24-отсутствует в документации, 28 не выдается через oauth. Остальное все запрашиваете.

Comment: https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=51851697&redirect_uri=https://gt99.ru/Bunker/Admin/docs.php&scope=message&display=page&response_type=code

вот вариант с message, но все равно scope заменился, в данномслучае на 0

Comment: если быть более внимательным и писать `messages` а не `message` то поди нормально будет.

Comment: Это не рашет проблему. Scope заменяется всегда на какой-то другой если я ему отдаю id своего приложения

Comment: приложение то standalone типа? домен указанный в приложении совпадает с тем что в redirect_uri ?

Comment: Теперь при создании standalone вк принудительно предлагает создать приложение 
в "удобном сервисе" https://id.vk.com/about/business/go/
где при создании приложения нет галочки standalone вовсе